# Version in jar name

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

When I import mvn project into Intellij the jar file it generates doesn't include version. But mvn generated jar has `name-version.jar` format. So I end up with two jar files one with version and another without one. I can of course, change module name in Intellij settings to include version. But that will be reset whenever I change pom file.

Maybe somebody else had a better idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The jar name that Maven generates *on disk* is controlled by `/project/build/finalName` so if you edit your `pom.xml` to look like

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

and then Maven will be generating the jar file without the version.

### Note

`finalName` only controls the name of the file on disk. Once that file is transferred into the local repository cache or a remote repository it will be renamed to match the repository layout (i.e. `${artifactId}-${version}.${type}` or `${artifactId}-${version}-${classifier}.${type}` for artifacts with a classifier). You cannot change the format used by the repository.

I add the above note because the first thing everyone seems to want to do upon learning about the `finalName` parameter is try and change the name in the repository.

Comment: `finalName` only changes the name of folder in target directory. It doesn't change the name of generated jar file.

Comment: Check your effective pom because unless you have something overriding the defaults, [finalName controls the name of the jar file also](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#finalName)

Comment: I couldn't find anything. I use war packaging and also `maven-war-plugin` to generate exploded war.

Comment: Well if you are talking about the `.jar` file that ends up in `WEB-INF/lib` then that is controlled by [`outputFileNameMapping`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#outputFileNameMapping) something like `@{artifact.artifactId}.@{artifact.extension}` should have the effect you are after, but a better solution (and the recommended solution BTW) is to build the `.jar` in a separate module entirely and pull it in as a dependency

Answer (score 2):

use version tag of the maven

```
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

do not let  intellij to create jar files without version tag.

Comment: That is what I am trying to find out. How shall i force Intgellij to include version in the filename?

Comment: intellij couldnt not pass version numbers, also it is not safe to let ide to build a versioning byself. i suggest you write with hand all versions except sub modules. (they can take parent version number)